# Oracle: Using CASE statement variable in an operation

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, 
       PLAYER_CD, 
       TEAM_ID, 
       USR_FNM, 
       USR_MNM, 
       USR_LNM,
       CASE 
           WHEN TEAM_ID = '11111111111111' THEN SIGN_DT
           ELSE START_DT
       END AS ASGN_DT
FROM PLAYER P 
JOIN TEAM T ON P.PLAYER_TEAM_ID = T.TEAM_ID 
JOIN USR U ON P.PLYAER_USR_ID = USR_ID;
```

I am trying to add the following field to the SELECT query to get number of days from the date retrieved using the `CASE` statement until now:

```
(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(ASGN_DT))
```

But when I do, I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "ASGN_DT": invalid identifier

Answer (score 2):

Don't `trunc` the alias `ASGN_DT`, but the `case` instead

```
 CASE 
       WHEN TEAM_ID = '11111111111111' THEN SIGN_DT
       ELSE START_DT
   END
```

You can also replace the long `case` statement with a shorter [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function:

```
 decode(TEAM_ID, '11111111111111', SIGN_DT, START_DT)
```

Comment: Same error displayed either way. I need a way to use `ASGN_DT` within the subtraction operation.

Comment: Show error using `trunc(sysdate-decode(TEAM_ID, '11111111111111', SIGN_DT, START_DT)`

Comment: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`

Answer (score 1):

`ASGN_DT` is the final alias you'll see in the resultset, but it's not visible from the query itself.

Solution? Wrap your query as a subquery. For the external query, the column `ASGN_DT` will be visible. For example:

```
select
    *,
    (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(ASGN_DT)) as diff
from (
  SELECT PLAYER_ID, 
         PLAYER_CD, 
         TEAM_ID, 
         USR_FNM, 
         USR_MNM, 
         USR_LNM,
         CASE 
             WHEN TEAM_ID = '11111111111111' THEN SIGN_DT
             ELSE START_DT
         END AS ASGN_DT
  FROM PLAYER P 
  JOIN TEAM T ON P.PLAYER_TEAM_ID = T.TEAM_ID 
  JOIN USR U ON P.PLYAER_USR_ID = USR_ID
) x;
```

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) as well.

Comment: Using the asterisk will initialize this error: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Answer (score 0):

I used a sub-query within my join, as shown below, to achieve what I was trying to do.

```
SELECT PLAYER_ID, 
       PLAYER_CD, 
       TEAM_ID, 
       USR_FNM, 
       USR_MNM, 
       USR_LNM,
       ASGN_DT
FROM PLAYER P 
JOIN (SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TEAM_ID = '11111111111111' THEN SIGN_DT
        ELSE START_DT
    END AS ASGN_DT
    FROM TEAM T) T ON P.PLAYER_TEAM_ID = T.TEAM_ID 
JOIN USR U ON P.PLYAER_USR_ID = USR_ID;
```